Text() and .navigationBarTitle() have different left margin
In this code, Text("Text 2") has a smaller margin to the left side of the screen than .navigationBarTitle("Text 1"). It's on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
How can I align the left margin for them to be the same?

If you check this code on iPhones with smaller sizes iPhone SE (Xcode), the margin is approximately the same, but it varies constantly.
Many thanks for your help!
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Text 2")
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .navigationBarTitle("Text 1")
        }
    }
}


Please see [ask] including the section about including code as text and not images

I don't see any reason for them to align. I'd just put two Texts in a VStack, instead of one of them being the navigation title.

The navigation title comes with its own styling and positioning. The default left margin on an iPhone 15 and an iPhone SE appears to be 16pt.
The content in the NavigationStack would normally occupy the full screen width. You have applied .padding() to your VStack, so this is why your smaller text has the margin that you are seeing. But as Sweeper remarked in a comment, there is no reason why this (unspecified) padding should match the (native) margin of the navigation title.
You can get it to work more consistently on iPhones by specifying the size of the horizontal padding (at least, based on current devices and iOS version):
NavigationStack {
    VStack {
        // ...
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, 16) //  HERE
    .navigationBarTitle("Text 1")
}

Unfortunately, this doesn't work quite so well on iPads, because the native margin for the title seems to be larger on iPads. So using this approach, you might have to consider making the padding dependent on the device size.
If you want to be sure that the title always aligns with the content then you might be better off replacing the native navigation title with your own custom title. The answer to Change NavigationStack title font, tint, and background in SwiftUI shows how this can be done.
